# Validation within workflow in Joomla component with MVC pattern

Tags: php, model-view-controller, validation, joomla

I'm writing a custom component for the Joomla CMS using the MVC pattern. I'm implementing a simple workflow, where I want the user to enter some data into a view, validate this data (on server side, this is not about client side/JavaScript validation) and redirect the user to another view, if the validation succeeded. If the data is invalid, the first view should be displayed again with the invalid fields marked.

Now I'm not sure, where to place the validation code: My first thought was to place it in the controller, since this one has to decide whether to redirect to the second view or not. But I found a couple of advices telling me *not* to place validation code in the controller.

Placing it into the model of the first view would also be an option. But since in Joomla there's a 1-to-1 relationship between model and view, I'm not sure if it's ok to only create a model class (because in case of successful validation, the first view is not shown again).

Is there any standard way to do this? Or is this kind of behaviour implemented in some standard component, so I could look for the source code? Any ideas (some pseudo-code would be nice and sufficient...)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I haven't worked with Joomla! in about 2 years but because you will be sending to a different work flow I would be using the controller, the model can be problematic for validation in some MVC models I have worked with. If the user was staying in the same work flow then I would use the view for validation.

Answer (score 2):

In my projects, I put them in the Form model (using [HTML_QuickForm2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2)).

Semi code:

```
$form = new HTML_QuickForm2();
$form->addElement('text')->addRule('email');
if ($form->validate()) {
    echo "all fine, storing in database";
} else {
    //error, let's try it again
    echo $form;
}
```

This way, you have all the rules and validations in your form object. Move the form initialization code into an own class extending HTML_QuickForm2, and you're set.

Comment: Thx for the hint. I'm not sure, if HTML_QuickForm2 works well together with Joomla, but I'll try to implement something similar.